# SMTP MIME header with attachment

Tags: php, email, smtp, mime, email-headers

I am trying to create a PHP function to send an e-mail using SMTP with an attachment. I am having a hard time trying to create the MIME headers as I want the body to include text in HTM format and the file to be attached.I am using a very old version of PHP (4.3.8) and this is the only method that is working. Tried PEAR, but won’t authenticate the SMTP correctly.

This is what I have so far:
I have edited this code as now I get the message correctly, but the file is corrupt. I changed the file into a text file and it starts out fine but then there appears a lot of garbage text.

```
$newLine = "\r\n";
$attachment="myFile.zip";
$message = "<br><h1><center>TEST MESSAGE</center></h1>" ;   


    //Body
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "     boundary=\"_e9e06aa5-1550-464d-ace4-e85b575d1899_\"" . $newLine . $newLine;   
    $newLine . $newLine;

    $headers .= "--_e9e06aa5-1550-464d-ace4-e85b575d1899_" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "     boundary=\"_7fdd1316-6f68-41bb-93f7-134933fc9aad_\"" . $newLine . $newLine;

    $headers .=  $message . $newLine;

    //$headers .= "--_7fdd1316-6f68-41bb-93f7-134933fc9aad_--" . $newLine; // If I leave this line it appears in the end of the message area.

    //Attachment
    $headers .= "--_e9e06aa5-1550-464d-ace4-e85b575d1899_" . $newLine;

    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;" . $newLine;
    $headers .= "    filename=" . $attachment . $newLine . $newLine;

    $handle = fopen($attachment, "rb");
    $contents = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $contents .= fread($handle, filesize($attachment));
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $contents = base64_encode($contents);

    $headers .= $contents . $newLine;
    $headers .= "--_e9e06aa5-1550-464d-ace4-e85b575d1899_--" . $newLine;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using ready class like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php)? It's much much eaysier. And there is version for PHP4.

Example:

```
require_once '../class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddAddress('whoto@otherdomain.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail()';
$mail->MsgHTML('Hello world');
$mail->AddAttachment('file.zip');
$mail->Send();
```

Making custom headers can make headache.

Comment: One of the requirements of phpmailer is that it requires PHP version 5 or later. Sadly, I can't make any updates to the server at the moment which is running on 4.3.8.

Comment: **"And there is version for PHP4."** Link for you - http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/

Comment: Using this code http://coffeeandpaste.blogspot.com/2009/02/phpmailer-smtp-authentication.html , since my SMTP is authenticated, but won't connect.

Comment: Is your SMTP is running thru SSL?

Comment: can you download https link for ex. "https://www.paypal.com/" ? If not you have no SSL module installed...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4667/discussion-between-rick-and-peter-szymkowski)

Comment: Got an older version and had to change the class.phpmailer.php file so that it pointed to the correct language/ folder. Also had to play with the SSL and uth properties. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the SMTP data stream looks like this: (empty lines are significant and all end with CRLF)

```
To: <joeuser@roadrunner.com> 
From: mary@roadrunner.com 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
Subject:email subject line 
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
  boundary="Z--Z=_CGI_Perl_Cookbook_=1409529510"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--Z--Z=_CGI_Perl_Cookbook_=1409529510
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable 
Content-Type: text/plain;   charset="us-ascii" 

Email message 
text 

--Z--Z=_CGI_Perl_Cookbook_=1409529510
Content-Disposition: attachment; 
   filename=attachment.txt
Content-Type: plain/text 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: None 

sometext data
attached to
the email

--Z--Z=_CGI_Perl_Cookbook_=1409529510--

. << \n\.\n to terminate the email
```

Answer (score 0):

Multipart/mixed mime message create script: https://github.com/breakermind/PhpMimeParser/blob/master/PhpMimeClient_class.php with attachments and inline messages, cc and bcc

```
$m = new PhpMimeClient();
// Add to
$m->addTo("email@star.ccc", "Albercik");
$m->addTo("adela@music.com", "Adela");
// Add Cc
$m->addCc("hello@email.be", "Ben");
$m->addCc("zonk@email.au");
// Add Bcc
$m->addBcc("boos@domain.com", "BOSS");    
// Add files inline
$m->addFile('photo.jpg',"zenek123");
// Add file
$m->addFile('sun.png');
// create mime
$m->createMime("Witaj księżniczko Alabambo",'<h1>Witaj księżniczko Alabambo <img src="cid:zenek123"> </h1>',"Wesołych świąt życzę!","Heniek Wielki", "heniek@domain.com");
// get mime
// $m->getMime();
// Show mime
echo nl2br(htmlentities($m->getMime()));
```